# Managing SQL Audits

Tags: sql-server

I am planning on using SQL Audits on the servers I manage and to have a more uniformed approach on setups, I was planning and writing my own management program in C#. Just wanted to check before I begin, that nobody else has thought of this and has released an open source tool.

My plan was to have something that would create Audits, Audits Specifications and some sort of data collection into a database. I've looked at Idera's Compliance Manager but that was too expensive for us to purchase.

Has anyone come across something like this before?

Comment: What are the additional functionalities that you plan adding with the C# program over native SSMS / DMV.

Comment: I wasn't planning anything that you can't do with SSMS but just something that would allow me to roll out that same specifications to to each database on every server (Enterprise only).

Comment: Are you confusing with [Administer Servers by Using Policy-Based Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/policy-based-management/administer-servers-by-using-policy-based-management)?

Comment: To be honest I never thought of using that. I'll have a look and see what it can do

Comment: I've looked at policy based management it rolling out polices using it seems a bit beyond it capabilities. I think I will stick with SMO and write my own program. Found this [Blog](https://colleenmorrow.com/2012/08/13/sql-audit-301-using-powershell-to-manage-audits/) that shows how to do it in Powershell.